# Maximization of Binary Multilinear Fractional Function

Tags: linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization

**Problem:** Let $a_{i,j}$, $b_{i,j}\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $(i,j)\in\left[m\right]^2$ such that $a_{i,j}=a_{j,i}$ and $b_{i,j}=b_{j,i}$. Let $z_k\in\{0,1\}$ for $k\in\left[m\right]$. We wish to maximize,

$f(z)=\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{(i,j)}a_{i,j}z_iz_j}{\displaystyle\sum_{(i,j)}b_{i,j}z_iz_j}$

Note that the numerator and denominator are assumed to be strictly positive.

**Thoughts:** I am aware of general notions of linear fractional programming. However, I am unsure whether the $z_iz_j$ terms/optimization over the hypercube will drastically change the availability of methods.

Comment: On possible simplification might be to introduce a new set of variables $y_{(i,j)}=z_iz_j$.

Comment: Would you be interested in (computable) relaxations of this problem?

Comment: Yes, relaxations are certainly of interest. Of course the main hope is to get an answer on the hypercube. Perhaps a relaxation might yield insight to the more restrictive solution?

Comment: When you say the numerator and denominator are strictly positive, do you mean that you optimize only over the set of z such that the denominator is nonzero?  It would seem that z=0 always makes the denominator zero.  Are you also interested in a version where (say) the $z_i$ are constrained to $\{-1,1\}$ and $B$ is positive definite so you don't have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This not a solution but a though. At least it gives you an easily computable upper bound.

First, look at it as a [generalized Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient#Generalizations).
As $B$ is positive definite, the [Cholesky decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CholeskyDecomposition.html) guarantees the existence of a matrix $U$ lower triangular with positive diagonal entries (and thus invertible) such that $B=U^*U$. We have
$$\frac{\langle z,Az\rangle}{\langle z,Bz\rangle}=\frac{\langle y,V^*AVy\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle} \qquad \text{with}\qquad y=Uz \quad\text{ and }\quad V=U^{-1}.$$
Let $$C = V^*AV\qquad \text{and}\qquad\mathcal D =\Big\{\frac{U^{-1}z}{\|U^{-1}z\|_2}\ \Big|\ z\in\{0,1\}^n\Big\}$$ 
We have then
$$ \max_{z\in\{0,1\}^n}f(z) = \max_{y\in \mathcal{D}}\langle y,Cy\rangle\leq \max_{\|y\|_2=1}\langle y,Cy\rangle=\rho(C).$$
where $\rho(C)$ denotes the spectral radius of $C$.